# MongoDB get items have no children

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, mongodb-query, pymongo, adjacency-list

There is a tree structure with parent reference (aka adjacency list). 
MongoDB collection data example is below:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "id" : 1,
    "name": "Digital Cameras",
    "url" : "digital-cameras",
}

/* 2 */
{
    "id" : 2,
    "name": "Nikon",
    "url" : "nikon",
    "parent_url": "digital-cameras"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "id" : 3,
    "name": "Canon",
    "url" : "canon",
    "parent_url": "digital-cameras"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "id" : 4,
    "name": "Film cameras",
    "url" : "film-cameras"
}
```

So tree structure is below:

```
Digital Cameras
|__Nikon
|__Canon

Film Cameras
```

How to find items, which has no children (aka leaves in tree terminology)? 
In my example result should point to `Nikon`, `Canon` and `Film Cameras` groups.

I have a query to find child items:

```
self.db.groups.find({'parent_url': {'$exists': True}})
```

So for every record A of my needed set there is no record B, where B.parent_url = A.url.

My stack is python 2.7, mongodb 2.6.5, pymongo 3.4.

Comment: You might need to be a bit more specific to your actual case here. You should be showing what you are actually storing and what is available to store. Simple strings are not a very reliable way of identifying an ancestry and you probably are using some type of unique identifier instead.

Comment: I store groups of eshop, each group can have 0 or one parent. I've modified the example (real data has the same structure, except they have images, meta titles and some other meta-tags).

Comment: Understand here that clearly your real data does not use the names `"parent"` and `"child"` as the actual content in those fields. We need a much clearer picture of what you are actually doing in order to advise how to best store it. There is no "easy query" to simply say "has no more children". But you can structure to make such an easy query possible. But you don't sufficiently describe what you are actually doing so we could advise.